# sending and recieving an ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I looked for ages to prevent this being a duplicate but i can't seem to find an answer.

On a previous jquery page i used the following ajax call:

```
var daynum1 = $(this).text();
var month1 = $('.ui-datepicker-month').text();
var year1 = $('.ui-datepicker-year').text();
var myDate = daynum1 + " " + month1 + " " + year1;
$('#headingcontent').html(myDate);

$.ajax({
  url: "events.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { myDate: myDate },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(html) {
    $("#eventcontent").empty();  
    $("#eventcontent").append(html);
  }
});
```

This worked absolutely perfectly. events.php was able to pick up the variable using:

```
if(isset($_POST['myDate']))
```

However I've come to use a different AJAX call to send data to a different page:

```
var titleevent = $("#dropdowntextbox").val();

$.ajax({
  url: "editevents2.php",
  cache: false,
  data: { titleevent: titleevent },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(html) {
    $("#editeventspopup").empty();  
    $("#editeventspopup").append(html);
  }
});
```

However I can't for the life in me get it working! The page that should receive the call has this set:

```
if(isset($_POST['titleevent']))
{
  $title = $_POST['titleevent'];
  echo "hooray found it";
}
else
{
  echo "hello";
}
```

Every single time, `hello` is all that is echoed. I've tried to add and alert to print the data back to me on success but i'm quite new to this so it just stopped it from working altogether.

My guess (which doesn't mean much) is because this variable is .val and not .html so its down the the data type. But i'm not sure what else i can set this to.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `$_POST['title']` -> `$_POST['titleevent']`. Closing as a typo

Comment: Also note that `$.ajax` defaults to `GET` so you need to set the type as well in order to use POST.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the typo in the question was my fault on writing the question not the code! edited the question, still doesn't work. thanks for the answers though!

Comment: @jeroen YES! thats all it was! i was stupidly missing this, thank you!!

Comment: your data (#dropdowntextbox) is null probably. could you inspect element when post data to editevents2.php page. and what did you see in requested  data.

Comment: and a suggestion please use camelCase or snake_case when define a variable or etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit it seems that the problem is just the type. The default type used by jQuery's `$.ajax()` method is GET. In order to use POST, you need to specify that:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "editevents2.php",
  type: "post",  // specify the type as POST
  cache: false,
  data: { titleevent: titleevent },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(html) {
    $("#editeventspopup").empty();  
    $("#editeventspopup").append(html);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are posting data with **titleevent** you will receive this on the server as **titleevent**.

You have this as your js code:

```
var titleevent = $("#dropdowntextbox").val();

 $.ajax({
  url: "editevents2.php",
  cache: false,
     data: {titleevent: titleevent},
     dataType: "html",
  success: function(html){
    $("#editeventspopup").empty();  
    $("#editeventspopup").append(html);
  }
});
```

You will receive it as:

```
if(isset($_POST['titleevent']))

        {

           $title = $_POST['titleevent'];

echo "hooray found it";

        }

        else
        {

echo "hello";
        }
```

Comment: sorry this was a typo in the question, it still doesn't work. Thank you though